# How to return a specific cell if another cell is equal to a given value, and also counting the amount of returned values (without duplicates)

Tags: microsoft-excel, automation

Currently I'm working on automating a small Excel file (see screenshot). So I have a list of standard themes, and a code that I have to fill in manually (this can't be automated). Next to that I have to count the amount of codes per theme, excluding duplicate values (which can be seen below the statistics column). Is there a way to do this easily without it becoming to complex? I really can't find a solution.

[image: Example Excel file]

Comment: Do you have Office 365 or 2021? Does your version of Excel support UNIQUE function?

Comment: @patkim Office 365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Excel 365, you can use a combination of `FILTER`, `UNIQUE` AND `COUNT` functions to get the unique counts. Then use SUM function for the total

```
=COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER($A$2:$B$20,$B$2:$B$20=D2)))
```

[image]

**Explanation**

First, we filter the table based on the given criteria.

[image]

We then return the unique columns

[image]

Finally, we count the unique rows to obtain result.

[image]

***EDIT***

In case the column contains characters, you should not use the [COUNT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/count-function-a59cd7fc-b623-4d93-87a4-d23bf411294c).

> The COUNT function counts the number of cells that contain numbers, and counts numbers within the list of arguments. Use the COUNT function to get the number of entries in a number field that is in a range or array of numbers.

As we are returning the number of rows, we can use the [ROWS function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rows-function-b592593e-3fc2-47f2-bec1-bda493811597) as it:

> Returns the number of rows in a reference or array.

[image]

Comment: This helped, thank you. Unfortunately I'm not able to mark this as answer. If somebody can do this for me.

Comment: @Masterrun80 Only you can mark the question as answered as your are the OP. Try again.

Comment: Done, thank you. One more question: The UNIQUE(FILTER(...)) functions work but it does not count the amount filtered. It returns 0. Is there another function for counting the amount filtered?

Comment: Maybe it's good to mention that I am not counting numbers but codes (including letters and numbers) instead.

Comment: @Masterrun80 Give an example of "it does not count the amount filtered". What is the format of your cell?

Comment: At first I copied your code completely. That didn't work because the number returned was 0. Then I rewrote your code from the inside out and that worked until the count function because it did not return a value greater than 0. I will include a image, but the functions are in dutch, Sorry.

Comment: The post has been updated and the screenshots are linked.

Comment: @Masterrun80 See EDIT part of the answer.